# Do I have to use 'by' only with a verb (when the preposition introduces an actor)?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Do I have to use 'by' only with a verb (when the preposition introduces an actor)? Can I drop the verb? For example

> The word “каратель” in Russian ("a punisher") is strongly associated with punitive operations against civilians [carried out] by the Nazis during World War II.

Comment: You can, but it might make the meaning clearer if you change it to 'operations by the Nazis against civilians'.

Comment: The only style issue is that if you drop it you just have one noun phrase after another which seems a bit repetitive.

Comment: @KateBunting Is it grammatical? Is 'by' in that sense mandated by English rules to follow some verb?

Comment: No, _by_ doesn't have to follow a verb. _'Hamlet' is a play by Shakespeare._